# Tableau method for two-variable first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

$FO^2$, i.e. two-variable first-order logic, has a NEXPTIME-complete satisfiability problem (see Grädel, Kolaitis and Vardi '97). However, the decidability and complexity of this fragment is proved by that paper in an indirect way, as far as I can tell.

What I need instead is an effective way to solve $FO^2$ satisfiability. What are the actual algorithms and methods available for this logic?

In particular, I would need a tableau-based method for $FO^2$ satisfiability. Is there any resource describing such a thing? Has it ever been developed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently a tableau for $FO^2$ has not been given explicitly but a tableau for the expressively equivalent description logic $ALBO^{id}$ has been given in:

Renate Schmidt and Dmitry Tishkovsky, [*Using Tableau to Decide Description Logics with Full Role Negation and Identity*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2559947),  ACM Trans. Comput. Log. 15(1): 7:1-7:31 (2014)

Answer (score 2):

You might check the FO2 solver by Tomer Kotek: https://forsyte.at/alumni/kotek/fo2-solver/ This is the only existing FO2 solver (Tony Tan with his student have a paper under submission, in which they proposed another algorithm, based on probabilistic methods).

I'm not aware of any tableaux algorithm for FO2.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! That solver looks interesting

Comment: Don't you know any tableau algorithm even in form of a tableau for some equivalent modal logic?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such Tableaux. FO2 is equivalent to the description logic ALCIOB. (or ALCIObHself extended with role negation). So I would recommend you to take a look at them.

Comment: I'm not an expert of description logics: does B stand for Boolean connectives over roles?

Comment: Yes. And small b stand for guarded combinations of roles. (so you cannot fully negate)

Comment: Thanks, so according to http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~ezolin/dl/, ALCB is already NEXPTIME-complete (without I and O). Is it still equivalent to $FO^2$?

Comment: No, ALCB is not equivalent to FO2. For example, it cannot state that every red element has an R-predecessor, which can be done with \forall{x} red(x) -> \exists{y} R(y,x)

Comment: Ok, so I need inverse roles, i.e. ALCIB. What about O? Are nominals needed?

Comment: \forall{x} \forall{y} A(x) /\ A(y) => x =y

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, after digging a bit into DLs I've found a tableau for an expressively equivalent description logic (I've added an answer). Thanks!

Comment: WOW, that's a great news! I was not aware of it